# retrieving data in VB from SQL

Tags: database, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I use Visual Basic 2010 and Microsoft SQL Server 2008. I have my database and my table and i made the connection (at least i think i did) in VB using only the interface.

What i want to know is how to get data from the database and use it into my VB project. I have of course searched for solutions already but the differences i find only confuse me more. What i need to know are the basics, the tools/objects and procedures to retrieve the data.

What i try to do at the moment is make a simple selection and put that data into a listbox right when the program starts, like this:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        SqlConnection1.Open()



        SqlConnection1.Close()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: VB.NET and VB6 are very different languages. If you are using .NET, don't tag VB6.

Comment: Here is the second part of my issue if anyone is willing to help   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14917829/retrieving-data-from-sql-in-vb-part-2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Create your connection string

```
Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=localhost;........."
```

2) Connect to your Database

```
Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
conn.Open()
```

3) Create a Command and the query

```
Dim command As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Product", connection)
Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()  //Execute the Query
```

4) Retrieve your result. There are several ways

```
Dim dt As New DataTable()
dt.Load(reader)

'Close the connection
connection.Close()
```

5) Bind to your list box

```
myListBox.ItemSource = dt
```

Full code here

```
Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Dim command As New SqlCommand("Select * from Products", connection)
    command.Connection.Open()
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()
 End Using
```

For more info

- [SQLCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx)

Comment: I'd suggest wrapping the creation of the command object in a Using statement, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection1.Open()
using table As DataTable = New DataTable
  using command as SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT blah blah", SqlConnection1)
    using adapter As SqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command)
      adapter.Fill(table)
    end using
  end using

  for each row As DataRow in table.Rows
    '  add each listbox item
    listbox1.Items.Add(row("column name"))
  next
end using
SqlConnection1.Close()
```