# How to fetch a particular column from Ms Access Database in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

How do I read a particular column from database..

```
myConnection.Open()

Dim str As String = "SELECT fullname' FROM STUDENTS"
Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)

dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

Dim dt As New DataTable

dt.Load(dr)

ListBox1.DataSource = dt
myConnection.Close()
```

Instead of getting the actual content of the database, what I get is  System.Data.DataRowView

Comment: I have formatted your code properly, i.e. consistent indenting and no wads of empty lines.  Please do so yourself in future.  If you make your code as easy for us to read as possible then you are more likely to get people willing to help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [retrieving data from SQL in VB (part 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14917829/retrieving-data-from-sql-in-vb-part-2)

Comment: Is the apostrophe in `"SELECT fullname' FROM STUDENTS"` a typo?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `DisplayMember` property of the `ListBox` to the name of the column you want displayed.  If you don't do that, you will see the result of calling `ToString` on each item, which is why you are seeing the name of the type of the items.  Note that you should set the `DisplayMember` before setting the `DataSource`.